# Return more than 6mb of data from AWS lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a case where i want to return atleast 10MB worth of data from AWS lambda, since knowing the limit of AWS lambda, we cant give back more than 6MB.

Any solution would be appreciated?

Answer (score 12):

This is how I solved it.

We wrote the response to S3 bucket and gave a redirect url to the caller. The response will go directly from S3 bucket.

The redirect url can be authenticated via Cloudfront to S3.

Hope it helps.

**EDIT1:**

Also after reading the documentation, addressing the OP's question on S3 lag after write.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Introduction.html#ConsistencyModel

With S3 consistency model, Please perform a get before you write. That is the ceveat that is documented on the above link.

Comment: I tried this solution, but the problem is we have some users who have really slow internet speed and it lags most of the time! so i want to avoid S3.

Comment: I don't understand what is lagging. If S3 confirms object is persisted it is stored and when requested from the storage, it will get you the data. Also Architecturally, if you are returning 10MB of data there is something wrong in your design.

Comment: @Kamal Enable transfer acceleration on the S3 bucket, or place CloudFront in front of it.

Comment: @kamal No matter which solution is chosen, the client has to download the 10MB response correct? Having a slow internet connection would impact the 10MB download independent of the solution. If that is the case why are you avoiding s3?

Comment: @Kannaiyan Laggin means with data transfer speed.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the solution, I just figured out a great way to pass more than 6MB worth of data, so that i could go away with S3. 

I can compress my data in lambda and using pako(https://github.com/nodeca/pako) on front end to unzip/uncompress it.

Comment: With S3 lot of maintaince is required. because y to go for storage when you have other options, next is you gonna store unnecessary those files and have to delete later since they are not required.

Comment: Compression is not a scalable solution. You will hit a compressed 6MB limit and look for other options. Also you need to extra coding to server and client code to handle it. With our scenario, we delete with a lifecycle rule of 24 hours. That worked for us in a scalable and simplistic way.

Comment: Thanks . will take a look for sure!

Comment: Yes. I recommend you should change to integrate lambda with S3 too. This is good architecture.

Comment: The 6MB limit is at the output of the lambda function, so in some cases is enough if you compress the output of the function. It is not fully scalable as @Kannaiyan says, but in my case was enough: 890KB compressed output -> 21MB of XML